# Unsure why Plot3D is empty?

Tags: plotting

I don't understand why my 3D Plot is empty so was looking for some advice. I have several functions defined, one of which is used in Plot3D, as seen below.

```
b = Sqrt[0.75];
L = b; 
lambda = 1.11; 
pi = 3.141592653589793;

Qn[n_] := (
Sqrt[(b/lambda)^2 + (2*pi*n*b)^2];
)

V0[y_] := (   
(Exp (b/lambda)/(Exp[b/lambda] - 1))*(Exp[-y/lambda] + 
          Exp[-(L - y)/lambda] + Exp[-(y + b/2)/lambda] + 
          Exp[-(L - y + b/2)/lambda]);   
)

V[x_, y_] := (   
b*pi*(V0[y] + Sum[Cos[2*pi*i*x]*((Exp[-L*Qn[i]/(2*b)]*
      Cosh ((y - L/2)*(Qn[i]/b))/(Qn[i]*
      Sinh[Qn[i]/2]))*(1 + (-1)^(i)*Exp[-Qn[i]/2])), {i, 3}]);   
)

Plot3D[V[x, y], {x, 0, wdth}, {y, -hght, hght}]
```

and Mathematica just outputs an empty plot. Thanks in advance for any help, hopefully I have just missed something simple.

Comment: What are the values for `wdth` and `hght`?

Comment: Minor comment: parentheses around your functions are not wrong, but they are not necessary. That is, you can write `Qn[n_] :=Sqrt[(b/lambda)^2 + (2*pi*n*b)^2];` rather than `Qn[n_] := (Sqrt[(b/lambda)^2 + (2*pi*n*b)^2];)`, for example.

Answer (score 5):

```
wdth = 1;

hght = 1;

b = Sqrt[0.75];
L = b;
lambda = 1.11;
pi = 3.141592653589793;

Qn[n_] := (Sqrt[(b/lambda)^2 + (2*pi*n*b)^2]);

V0[y_] := ((Exp [b/lambda]/(Exp[b/lambda] - 1))*(Exp[-y/lambda] + 
      Exp[-(L - y)/lambda] + Exp[-(y + b/2)/lambda] + 
      Exp[-(L - y + b/2)/lambda]));

V[x_, y_] := (b*
    pi*(V0[y] + 
      Sum[Cos[2*pi*i*
          x]*((Exp[-L*Qn[i]/(2*b)]*
            Cosh [(y - L/2)*(Qn[i]/b)]/(Qn[i]*
               Sinh[Qn[i]/2]))*(1 + (-1)^(i)*Exp[-Qn[i]/2])), {i, 
        3}]));

Plot3D[V[x, y], {x, 0, wdth}, {y, -hght, hght}]
```

[image]

1. Use `Cos[]` not `Cos()`
2. Use `Exp[]` not `Exp()`
3. Do not use `)` after the semicolon use it before.
4. The best way to debunk your code is to try give a numerical value to your functions, i.e., `Qn[1]`, `V0[1]`, `V[1,1]`